# jQuery UI draggable: Use other element for containment and snapTo calculation

Tags: jquery, user-interface, draggable, containment

I have 2 elements that both need to be dragged. The simplified markup is as follows:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="item" src="foo.jpg" />
    <ul class="buttons">
        <li>Crop</li>
        <li>Resize</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

They need to be contained in an area and also snapTo certain elements in that area. The problem is that I want draggable to look at `.item` and not `.wrapper` when calculating how it should be contained. Because the buttons area positioned slightly outside `.item`.

If I use draggable on `.item`, `.wrapper` does not move along.

If I use draggable on `.wrapper`, `.item` can not be positioned completely to the top, right or bottom of the element used for containment.

Simplified code:

```
$('.wrapper').draggable ({
    containment: '.page',
    snap: '.page-grid',
    snapMode: 'inner',
    snapTolerance: 20
});
```

[image: Explanation of the situation]

Does anybody have an idea on how to solve this? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't have `overflow:hidden` applied to your wrapper then just make the wrapper exactly the same measurements as your item. You still can position your buttons with negative values like: `bottom:-5px`. This way they will stay the same way like you have them now with that slight padding on your wrapper.

```
#wrapper{ padding:0 }
.buttons{position:absolute; bottom:-5px;right:-5px}
```

Comment: Awesome! That I did not think of this before... jesus haha. Thanks